# Order result using LINQ and cast type

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to *order* a list and take the *top* item. I can't set it to the type I need it to be.

```
var testFiles = new List<FileProcessing>();
testFiles = GetAll(var1, var2, var3, var3);

result = testFiles.OrderByDescending(item => item.DateRowAdded).Take(1);
return result;
```

I've got **compile time error**

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable to 'myType'.

Comment: `Take()` returns a list of items in the form of an `IEnumerable` (which contains a single item, but is still a list). use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` to return a single item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `.Take(size)` returns a `IEnumerable<T>` (not single `T`) of size at most `size`. So you can put either

```
 var array = testFiles
   .OrderByDescending(item => item.DateRowAdded)
   .Take(1)
   .ToArray();

 return array.Length > 0
   ? array[0]
   : SomeCustomDefaultValue; // when testFiles is empty
```

Or

```
 return testFiles
   .OrderByDescending(item => item.DateRowAdded)
   .FirstOrDefault(); // when testFiles is empty
```

Please, note that 2nd version being conciser doesn't allow to provide (in general case) custom default value.

Finally, if `testFiles` is (very) *long* and thus sorting (`OrderByDescending`) is *slow* and memory consuming, you can try `Aggregate`:

```
 return testFiles
   .Aggregate((bestSoFar, current) => bestSoFar.DateRowAdded > current.DateRowAdded 
      ? bestSoFar
      : current);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @DimitryBychenko

Comment: You can do `.DefaultIfEmpty(SomeCustomDefaultValue).First()` to ensure that there is a value.